# How long is a clearance void time valid?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules

You're picking up your IFR clearance on the ground and you get a 10 minute void time from now.

What phase of flight is that 10 minute void time clearance good until?

..your wheels are up?
..a certain altitude?
..on course?
..your initial call to ATC?
..or is it from when ATC gives your position report and says "radar contact"?

Comment: I added the FAA tag because your previous questions have been about the US. When you ask about regulations or procedures, please always tell us which country you're asking about, because they're different around the world. If you're actually asking about some other country, please just re-tag the question as necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Since you didn't state jurisdiction, I'm assuming US.

From the AIM:

> **1. Clearance Void Times.** A pilot may receive a clearance, when operating from an airport without a control tower, which contains a
>   provision for the clearance to be void if not airborne by a specific
>   time. A pilot who does not depart prior to the clearance void time
>   must advise ATC as soon as possible of their intentions. ATC will
>   normally advise the pilot of the time allotted to notify ATC that the
>   aircraft did not depart prior to the clearance void time. This time
>   cannot exceed 30 minutes. Failure of an aircraft to contact ATC within
>   30 minutes after the clearance void time will result in the aircraft
>   being considered overdue and search and rescue procedures initiated.

The requirement is to be airborne prior to the clearance void time. You need to contact ATC within 30 minutes of the void time either in the air or to notify them that you did not depart.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is actually in the wording of the clearance itself. This is from the [FAA's ATC orders](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf), section 4-3-4:

> **PHRASEOLOGY−**
>   CLEARANCE VOID IF NOT OFF BY (clearance void time)

You must be "off", i.e. airborne, by the void time. See also the definition in [the P/CG](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/PCG_10-12-17.pdf):

> **CLEARANCE VOID IF NOT OFF BY (TIME)−**
>   Used by ATC to advise an aircraft that the departure clearance is automatically canceled if
>   takeoff is not made prior to a specified time. The pilot must obtain a
>   new clearance or cancel his/her IFR flight plan if not off by the
>   specified time.

Answer (score -1):

That would be contact after takeoff. The 10 minutes is your interval to get yourself into the controller's airspace and report yourself as such.